# Call function after event block has executed in GWT

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT and have a button that upon being clicked should filter the data being displayed in my CellTable and then hide some of the columns.

```
filterButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick (ClickEvent event) {
        //some working code here to get the minimum and maximum
        filter(min, max);
        hideCols();
    }
});
```

My problem is here. I've found (from https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#celllist) that the ListDataProvider binds the Celltable to my list and any changes to the list will be reflected in the views. The views are updated at the end of the current event block, which causes my problem. I call hideCols() in the current event block and it hides the columns but then, as far as I understand, the view is updated upon exiting the block and the columns are redrawn. Is there any way to have hideCols() run after the ListDataProvider has completely finished?

```
filter(int min, int max) {
    for (SiteInfo site : displayedList)
        if (site.num_zones >= min && site.num_zones <= max)
            filteredList.add(site);
    dataProvider.getList().clear();
    dataProvider.getList().addAll(filteredList);
    siteTable.setRowCount(filteredList.size());
}
```

Lastly here is the hideCols() function. I know it works properly because I call it successfully elsewhere in my code. The first line hides the column headers and the second line takes care of the rows for the respective columns.

```
private native void hideCols()/*-{
    $wnd.jQuery("span.toHide").parent().hide();
    $wnd.jQuery(".toHide").hide();
}-*/;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can redraw synchronously using [`flush()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.html#flush%28%29).

But IMO you should fix your `hideCols`: use [`addColumnStyleName`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.html#addColumnStyleName%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) to add a class with [`visibility: collapse`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns), or alternately [remove the cols](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.html#removeColumn%28int%29) from the `CellTable`.

And to answer your question, you can use [`Scheduler.get().scheduleFinally`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleFinally%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29) (or `scheduleDeferred` if *finally* is not late enough).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I had originally used `refresh()` but the columns came back. How does `flush()` differ?

I tried adding styles to the columns as you mentioned but nothing seemed to happen. I was able to remove the columns from the table, but then couldn't get them back if I needed them again.

I did not try using `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred`.

What I ended up doing for now is creating a second table with only the columns I want not hidden and toggling their visibility as required. It's not a very nice solution but it's working.

Comment: I made a few corrections to my answer, and added links to the javadocs for the method. This clarifies that I meant `CellTable#flush()` rather than `ListDataProvider#flush()`, for instance. Too add your columns back, use `insertColumn()`; this should trigger a redraw, but you can call `redraw()` on the `CellTable` to make sure.